# Firefox 8.0beta - migrating profile from v4.0

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, migration, firefox-profile

I'm running Firefox 8.0beta2 on a Lenovo/Vista machine.  Runs fine.  I'd like to migrate my addons, cookies and bookmarks from my old Firefox to the v8.0beta.  I also have v4.0.1 installed and it also runs fine (have 2 profiles and the Firefox installs are in different folders).  I copied the contents from my 4.0 profile folder (in AppData) to the 8.0beta profile folder.  Still seems to run fine, but no addons, etc.  Is there an easy way to migrate addons, cookies and bookmarks from the old version?

Comment: Does 4.0 have firefox sync? I know there are other addons for this (FEBE comes to mind) but sync might be easiest. I've never used it, though, so IDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks should be easiest to migrate, Firefox uses a single bookmarks.html file that you can replace assuming 8.0 hasn't changed format or how to store them etc.

Addons are usually limited in the version of FF they support, and unless you disable that check you'll end up updating them - much better to do that imho rather than try to override the check.

Cookies idk, there may be a way to copy them over but why would you really want to; unless there are sites where you're logged in and forgot the password? ;) Just login again once instead of moving the entire bunch of old moldy cookies :D